# reading C++ binary file in Java

Tags: java, c++, binaryfiles

I have a 500MB binary file. with a bunch of float entries. It was written by a C++ program. I would load it in C++ like this.

```
void load(char f_name[], int size, float data[])
{
    std::fstream f_bin(f_name, std::ios::in|std::ios::binary);

    f_bin.seekg(std::ios::beg);
    f_bin.read((char*)data, size*sizeof(float));
    f_bin.close();
}

float *data;
int size = 123456789;
data = new float[size];
load("myFile.bin", size, data);
```

And i can access the float values: data[x]; In c++ it works preatty fast. Is there something simular in java?

**Edit**
After reading a bit around i have this so far:

```
        RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile("C://path//myFile.bin", "r");
        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)f.length()];
        f.read(bytes);

        float fl = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getFloat();     


        System.out.println(fl);
```

Which prints the **first** float entry. Now i should loop float by float and put it in an array like `float[] data`.

Comment: You might wanna take a look at: [RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) for reading and writing bytes

Comment: I think it's **not a duplicate of** "File to byte[] in java": this question is about reading C++ generated data AND ESPECIALLY FLOATS in a java programme, whereas the other question is only about reading a file as a byte array.

Comment: _@user1930254_ Do you have control over the c++ implementation? It might be a better choice, to store these `float` values in text format, or have some language interop capable serialization framework like e.g. [google-protobuf](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in Java.

```
try(FileChannel fc = new RandomAccessFile("myFile.bin", "rw").getChannel()) {
    FloatBuffer fb = fc.map(MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, fc.size())
                       .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
    // use fb 
}
```

This is quite a bit faster as it memory maps the file and avoids a memory copy (you can do the same in C++)

Comment: @user1930254 it's super fast in C too if you use memory mapped files.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, I have a similar situation where I have written objects of a user-defined class into a file in binary mode from c++ and wants to read it from java. how should I change the above code to achieve that? would you kindly include the answer to this in your answer?

Comment: @ChiefA I am not familiar with C++ any more.

Answer (score 1):

The Java standard is very precise about how floating points are to be represented:

> [**Java virtual machine specification 2.3.2:**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.3.2) The floating-point types are float and double, which are conceptually associated with the
>   32-bit single-precision and 64-bit double-precision format IEEE 754
>   values and operations as specified in IEEE Standard for Binary
>   Floating-Point Arithmetic (ANSI/IEEE Std. 754-1985, New York).

But the C++ standard doesn't give many guarantees regarding this:

> **C++11 standard 3.9.1/8:** There are three floating point types: float, double, and long double. The type double provides at least as much precision as
>   float, and the type long double provides at least as much precision as
>   double.  (...) The value representation of floating-point types is
>   **implementation-defined**.

With [`<limits>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/limits/numeric_limits/?kw=numeric_limits) you can in a portable way know a little bit more about your floats:  `std::numeric_limits<float>::is_iec559` will for example tell you if the  IEC-559 / IEEE-754 standard (aka the same as java) is used:

- If it is,  you could then read the float, using binary data as it is.  (*Edit following PoweredByRice comment; in fact you still have to address potential endianness issues, because IEEE-754 leaves this point open.  For more info on how to force a specific ordering on the C++ side, [look here](https://www.gamedev.net/articles/programming/general-and-gameplay-programming/writing-endian-independent-code-in-c-r2091).  On the java side you can force a byte ordering or use the default one*).
- If not, you'll have to read the bytes and write floating point format conversion routines, which usually proves to be challenging.

Comment: This answer while correctly mentions the importance of size, does not mention the other half of the picture that is endianness.

Comment: @PoweredByRice indeed,  IEEE 754 does not specify endianness, so that there is a risk of incompatibility between different architectures.

Comment: @PoweredByRice post edited accordingly.  Thanks for the hint !